# spark loading 150 million records into MySQL taking 2-3 hours

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have spark proses which are doing some calculations then it's doing an insert into MySQL table, all calculation done in 40-50 minutes but. Write into the table is 2-3 hours (depends on DB usage). I tried to do batchsize

```
val db_url_2 = "jdbc:mysql://name.amazonaws.com:port/db_name?rewriteBatchedStatements=true" 

df_trsnss.write.format("jdbc").option("url", db_url_2).option("dbtable", output_table_name).option("user", db_user).option("password", db_pwd).option("truncate","true").option("batchsize", 5000).mode("overwrite").save()
```

but it still taking forever to load, I can't afford to spend 2-4 hours a day just to calculate and write data into the table.

> **Is there any way to speed up this process?**

Start to think to do write into CSV and then load it into db from CSV so I can reduce EMR time.

Comment: are they innodb tables? What innodb buffer pool size do you have? What innodb log file size do you have? What SQL statement form does this apache-spark statement translate to?

Comment: @danblack it is InnoDB , statement is like `insert into table_name values (1,1,1),(2,2,2),....(n,n,n);` dont know about log file and buffer pool

Comment: ok - [starting point](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72750/innodb-import-performance) (look at second answer first - easier to read for a start). I assume batchsize means it commits after 5000 rows (or statements).

Comment: @danblack yes bachsize man that  insert has 5000 values (1,1,1)...(5000,5000,5000)

Comment: @danblack buffer is 12616466432 bytes = 12616.466432 MB so it should be enough, i don't have any indexes on that table

Comment: 12G buffer should be plenty. I'm assuming each insert is its own transaction (autocommit mode and no explicit begin transaction). `innodb_log_file_size` could be the issue. Check the documentation on changing size.

Comment: So, you are using a distributed processing framework but loading data on a *single* connection -- and complaining about lack of parallelism. Isn't that a bit ironic ?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter it is not single transaction , spark opens more than 200 connections to db when its is writing .

Comment: Did you ever resovle this?

Comment: @thebluephantom unfortunately no, still same issue , changed all variables still taking forever to do insert

Comment: Did u ever resolve?

Comment: @thebluephantom unfortunatley not :)

Comment: @Andrey Did u get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this - right from the DataBricks Guide in fact:

**JDBC writes**

Spark’s partitions dictate the number of connections used to push data through the JDBC API. You can control the parallelism by calling coalesce() or repartition() depending on the existing number of partitions. Call coalesce when reducing the number of partitions, and repartition when increasing the number of partitions.

Try and see how this compares to your write approach and let us know.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val df = spark.table("diamonds")
println(df.rdd.partitions.length)

// Given the number of partitions above, you can reduce the partition value by calling coalesce() or increase it by calling repartition() to manage the number of connections.
df.repartition(10).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(jdbcUrl, "diamonds", connectionProperties)
```

Comment: no doesnt work, still slow :( its just reduce number of connections to DB

Comment: That is interesting as it is the classical approach.

Comment: Mysql is not a fast database

Comment: What about Samsons comment? The approach increases number of connections and concurrencg on mysql. It may well be this is the best you can get nowrhaps mysql is working for many other users

Comment: I tried increase amount of connections but still didn't get result which will satisfy me :( still to slow or overload db so people cannot connect to it

Comment: I saw that post , but I dont have any indexes on table

Comment: @ thebluephantom i tried . do insert like thi `insert into table values (1,1); `and `insert into table values (1,1), (2,2),...(n,n); ` both slow (around 1 hour just . to write 150 million of rows) with the second its also taking almost  all resources so it became almost impossible to work with DB

Comment: looks like my innodb_log_file_size its to small to handle this amount of records, its only 128MB

Comment: Well try larger and let us all know

Comment: It may be well typical this scenario. What thruput r u expecting and based on what?

Comment: another problem that . i am using AWS and there is no way to modify innodb_log_file_size variable

Comment: So may be the timing is the best you can get

Comment: I change the file size to 3GB and it didnt help :/

Comment: What are your terms of reference that it should be faster?

Comment: its just 150 millions of records, I think it should be faster than almost an hour for doing insert

Comment: Short, long records? indexes? Load of system? Interesting.

Comment: about 9 columns mostly integers, no indexes , no rules of triggers , InnoDB table, usual load on system before its doing inserts around 5-10% I guess ill have to do something else, I try to dump all of this data into csv file and its 5GB :)